# Как взять нужный кусок от html кода (get request)

Tags: java, android, html, get, okhttp

Сделал я GET Request значит, и на выходе получился такой замечательный HTML код:

```
<html class=""><head>

        <title>Newest Questions - Stack Overflow</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">


        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow">
        <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
        <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com">
        <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Newest Questions">
        <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Stack Overflow | The World’s Largest Online Community for Developers">
        <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js"></script><script src="https://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js" async=""></script><script async="" src="https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script><script async="" src="https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_207.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=796de49f76c3"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=ae12ac33eee1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=88b742a16ed2">
```

Так вот, как вырезать весь код и оставить нужную мне строчку.
Например мне весь код не нужен а только

```
<title>Newest Questions - Stack Overflow</title>
```

Лучше и тег   обрезать, чтобы на выходе получилось так:

```
Newest Questions - Stack Overflow
```

Пользуюсь `okHttp`. Ну и для тех кто не понял: есть у меня HTML код, я его спарсил путем GET запроса с помощью okHttp, мне надо из того самого HTML кода взять пару строчек, которые мне нужны, а весь код... в мусор его.....

Comment: Как вариант, если надо просто доставать данные, то вам поможет jsoup библиотека

Comment: Она позволяет очень просто парсить данные из html

Answer (score 1):

```
 Implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://....").get();
String title = doc.title();
```